Flutter web app in mobile browser desktop view issue
I have been having issue with my app when using it on mobile browser the app simply won't load if desktop site is enabled in browser for Android.
At first it might be a issue cause i am migrating from an older version of flutter there might be some setting missing but even after trying for days couldn't solve it.
So I created a complete new app. Here are the steps I took
Flutter upgraded to latest stable version
Created a new folder and app using flutter create. Command
Run the app using
flutter run -d web-server --web-hostname <my ip address> --web-port 7357

It spins up successfully.
I enter the address in my mobile browser and it runs the counter app. Next I try to view the app in desktop site nothing show up; just a blank screen in my Samsung m15 5g and tried oneplus 12r as well same result.
I'm using flutter version 3.27.1.
When I run flutter doctor -v everything is green
Obviously the app runs fine in desktop browser using:
flutter run -d chrome

It works fine on iPhone chrome in both mobile and desktop view
Search the internet it suggest issue due to web renderer. Does
anyone know how I can fix this?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Its the code you get when you first create app

Please [edit] your question to add a [mre] so we can reproduce the issue.
